# Crop saved Image using com.android.camera.action.CROP on android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, crop, android-image

I have reads many question about this, but I still failed using this code... maybe anyone can corect my code... I want to crop an image from file that i know the location using com.android.camera.action.CROP like this...

```
    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri); 
    intent.putExtra("crop", true);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {               
        Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("intent");

        tampilan.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }

    File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            

    if (f.exists()) f.delete();
```

But when i run the code, nothing hapend... T.T
can anyone help me??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had modify my code and its works successfull, this is my code..

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );
    int size = list.size();
    if (size == 0) {            
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(selectImageUri);        
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_RESULT);
        } else {

        }

    }
```

and the activityResult like this

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        switch (requestCode){
        case SELECT_PICTURE :
            selectImageUri = data.getData();
            doCrop();
        break;
        case CROP_RESULT :
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {               
                bmp = extras.getParcelable("data");
                temporary.setBitmap(bmp);

            }
            File f = new File(selectImageUri.getPath());            

            if (f.exists()) f.delete();
            Intent inten3 = new Intent(this, tabActivity.class);
            startActivity(inten3);
        break;
        case CAMERA_IMAGE :
            doCrop();
        break;
        }
    }
```

maybe its useful :D

Comment: what does "com.android.camera.action.CROP" do? what if I already have an image from "android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE" or "Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" what do I do with that picture? Where do I need to start following your code?

Answer (score 1):

Using this intent is very risky. It's not even a part of the documentation. [**Here's**](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html) some more explanation about why it's a risky thing.
I suggest using a third party library for cropping, like [**this one**](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage).

Answer (score 0):

Then start the activity, use this

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

then use the following to get croped image

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)return;

        switch (requestCode) {

            case 1:         
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {               
                    photo = extras.getParcelable("data");               


                        tampilan.setBitmap(photo);
break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: yeah I already add that code, but still nothing happend and give a black bitmap.. the crop process still not show..

Comment: I tried the code,,, but it's give a force close eror when its run the startActivityForResult,,, do you know why its happend??

Comment: @adi.zean if you got solution for your own.. dont edit your question to post your solution.. Answer your own question and accept it. MAy it helps for others

Comment: owh im sorry for that.. OK i will edit back and answer my question.. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setDataAndType(mPhotoUri, "image/*");
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        Integer altura = documento.getAltura();
        Integer largura = documento.getLargura();
        if (altura != null && largura != null) {
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", altura);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", largura);
        }
        File file = imagemProcessor.getNewFile();
        mCropUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCropUri);
        intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CROP);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Context context = getBaseContext();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Your device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Context context = getBaseContext();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Fail to create file!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of just writing the code, try to elaborate your solution.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.