# Launch Crop intent and set cropped image as wallpaper

Tags: android, gallery, crop, wallpaper

I'm looking forward to cropping a picture and using it as wallpaper programatically .. any help please ?

Comment: see this link it will guide you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275842/crop-saved-image-using-com-android-camera-action-crop-on-android